# How can we configure tomcat to detect browser request and redirect them to https?

Tags: tomcat, redirect

I want to do http to https redirection in tomcat, but for only browser requests. All other requests should be bypassed. Can we achieve this by adding user-agent in security-constraints of web.xml ?